# Emacs not show Cyrillic text (UTF-8)

Tags: character-encoding

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10

I open by Notedpad++ text file.

Here result:
[image]

As you can see the encoded is UTF-8. And as result Notepad++ success show Cyrillic.
Nice.

Now I open same file by Emacs:
[image]

Why Emacs now show correct Cyrillic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this happens when Emacs ends up thinking that your file is not a text file but a binary file.  This tends to happen when the file contains NUL bytes.  Try `C-s C-q 0 RET C-s` to see if there's such a NUL byte somewhere.

You can also try `C-x RET r utf-8 RET` to reload the file as a utf-8-encoded file, just to make sure Emacs decodes it correctly when it's told which encoding to use (but it won't remember which encoding to use next time around, so it's not a real solution to your problem).

Comment: C-x RET r utf-8 RET  - this help. How config Emacs to do this automatically? To open text file in UTF-8 encoding. In my init.el I set "(set-language-environment "UTF-8")" - but this not help.